# Is it ladle or laddle?

Tags: orthography

The author of a book I'm working on insists that a **ladle**, a serving spoon for soup or stew, is spelled *laddle*.  A quick Google search pulled results of **ladle**, but most shopping sites and Youtube videos have *laddle*.

I'm most certain ***ladle*** is correct. But I need to know how and where she got *laddle*.

Comment: If you are already certain that "ladle" is correct, then your title doesn't seem to match your question. / The spelling "laddle" suggests a pronunciation that rhymes with "addle" (with the vowel sound found in the word "trap") which is not usual: the word "ladle" is generally pronounced with the vowel sound found in the word "face".

Comment: "But I need to know how and where she got laddle." Try to research and let us know what you found. Good Luck.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that *most* shopping sites and YouTube videos have "laddle". How did you reach that conclusion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

​According to Oxford, [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ladle), Merriam-Webster's Dictionaries,
there is the only spelling 'LADLE':

> **ladle**
>   a very big spoon with a long handle and a deep cup-shaped part, used especially for serving soup.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, there are several instances of the word spelt with a double-*d* over a long period.

> … the carpenter's man had a great iron **laddle** with which he used to supply  the workmen with hot stuff, and as two of the enemies entered the boat where the fellow stood, he saluted them with a full **laddle** of the hot boiling liquor …
>   (Daniel Defoe, "The Life and Most Surprising Adventures of Robinson Crusoe … The **[Ninth Edition](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6FtgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA280&dq=%22laddle%22)**.," A. Donaldson, **1769**)

OTOH,

> The Carpenter's Man had a great Iron **Ladle**, with …
>   (The [**Fourteenth Edition**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=10pProU9YjQC&pg=PA219&lpg=PA219&dq=%22had%20a%20great%20iron%20ladle%22)., J. Browne, **1779**)

Note the change to **single-*d*** in the latter edition.

*See also:*

- "Wills and Inventories Illustrative of the History, Manners, Language, Statistics, &c. of the Northern Counties of England, from the Eleventh Century Downwards.," Part I., London, p.[307](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=WD08AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA307&dq=%22laddle%22).(The quotation dates to **1569**)
- "[251. To Make CREAM CURDS](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=M34V8qqm17UC&pg=PT92&dq=%22laddle%22)" in Elizabeth Moxon, *English Housewifery Exemplified in Above Four Hundred and Fifty Receipts Giving Directions for Most Parts of Cookery,* Library of Alexandria, **1755**.
- Andrew Duncan (Jr.), "The Edinburgh New Dispensatory …" Bell and Bradfute, **1819**, [xc](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=cg47AAAAcAAJ&pg=PR90&dq=%22laddle%22).
- Matthew Prior, "Poems Upon Several Occasions," Vol.1, Kincaid and Creech, **1773**, p.[128](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=vA9MAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA128&dq=%22laddle%22)

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) shows 11 spellings of the word, over a period of 1000 years. Only one of them has 'dd' in it, and that is a Middle English spelling (from 1468) "laddil".

Kris has shown us a use of "laddle" from 1769, but that has not even made it into the OED. This suggests it is an isolated case - and evidently was not used in other editions.

Comment: I have included a reference to "Wills and Inventories Illustrative of the History, Manners, **Language**, Statistics, &c. of the **Northern Counties of England**, from **the Eleventh** Century Downwards.," (emphasis mine) that has an entry related to the year **1569**.

Comment: This English-Tagalog Translator [https://www.tagalogtranslate.com/en_tl/4898/laddle] also lists *sandok* (the Filipino word for ladle) to laddle.

Comment: @Almira: another isolated case, and (given the era) almost certainly simply an error.